# Knockout submit binding handler fails with disabled button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, font-awesome

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/DTcHh/1873/)

I'm using the `submit` binding handler on my form element. With focus on the "Invoice #" textbox in the 2nd row the user should be able to just hit the enter key, at which point my `self.Next()` function is called. However if the first button element in my form is disabled, the `submit` handler fails.

I've tried disabling the button with a `disabled` attribute, and with a `data-bind="enable:false"` attribute but that didn't matter. I've tried moving the HTML elements around, but it appears that no matter what elements I have in the form, if the first one is a button that's disabled, the `submit` binding handler fails.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="search-form" class="container">
    <form name="my-form" data-bind="submit: Next">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-default"><!-- disabled or data-bind="enable: false" -->
                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" disabled>
                    <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label class="control-label">Invoice #</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: InvoiceID"  autofocus="true"  />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" data-bind="click: Next">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This HTML works, but I've commented out the disabled attributes.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Thanks

**Edit** I should include that I'm not seeing any errors in the console, and I don't see anything in the rendered HTML that looks like the cause.

Comment: I don't know how bootstrap works but I think when it's trying to handle the enter press, it submits using the first submittable control (the button). It doesn't know to check if it is not disabled. Perhaps there's a way to tell bootstrap to specifically use the submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a knockout issue, but that the actual form `submit` event, which is what triggers the knockout logic, isn't firing.  (You can see this by setting an event breakpoint on the `submit` event in Chrome Dev Tools: the event is only fired when that first button isn't disabled)

A solution is just to add `type="button"` on your buttons that aren't submit buttons.

([Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grp00f3x/) after adding type "button", with both buttons disabled.)

Comment: Your solution works, thanks, but I think you have it out of order: "Knockout will prevent the browser’s default submit action for that form" and "the browser will call your handler function but will not submit the form."

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment; but knockout isn't "preventing" anything.  Knockout's logic is never triggered because it's attached to an event that is never fired.

Comment: I see what's going on. I created a regular HTML page with a form (no KO) and I'm seeing the same behavior if the first element is disabled. That quote was from the KO site's `submit` binding page - I thought it was saying KO was handling the enter key event, rather than the form's submit - my mistake.